# Get values in a specific time range and exclude (a huge amount of) gaps in SQL

Tags: python, sql, pandas

I want to get values in a time range between two dates and exclude some values in gaps between those two dates. My query works well with a small amount of gaps, however, sometimes I have to exclude a huge amount of gaps so that my query exceeds the maximum amount characters. Right now I'm concatenating `EXCEPT` queries for each time-gap I want to exclude. I'm sure there is some smarter way to do that, but I'm not so familiar with SQL.

I'm working with pandas `read_sql()` and passing the parameters with the `params` argument, in the example I wrote down readable values:

```
SELECT sv.Timestamp,
       sv.SignalID,
       s.SignalName,
       sv.Value
FROM SignalValue sv
       INNER JOIN Signal s ON s.SignalID = sv.SignalID
       INNER JOIN Device r ON r.DeviceID = s.DeviceID
WHERE  s.SignalName = Sensor1 AND r.DeviceId = 1 AND sv.timestamp >= '2019-02-04 00:00:00.000000' AND sv.timestamp <= '2019-02-11 23:59:59.999999'

EXCEPT SELECT sv.Timestamp,
              sv.SignalID,
              s.SignalName,
              sv.Value
FROM SignalValue sv
       INNER JOIN Signal s ON s.SignalID = sv.SignalID
       INNER JOIN Device r ON r.DeviceID = s.DeviceID
WHERE s.SignalName = Sensor1  AND r.DeviceId = 1 AND sv.timestamp BETWEEN '2019-02-04 05:15:20.099000' AND '2019-02-04 09:15:20.099000'

EXCEPT SELECT sv.Timestamp,
              .....
```

How can I do that exclusion in a shorter query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Keep only your first select and append the exclusion at the end

```
... AND sv.timestamp >= '2019-02-04 00:00:00.000000' AND sv.timestamp <= '2019-02-11 23:59:59.999999'
AND sv.timestamp NOT BETWEEN '2019-02-04 05:15:20.099000' AND '2019-02-04 09:15:20.099000'
...
```

A more elegant solution would be achieved if you could store your exclusion intervals in a separate table. Or if you cannot do that create a virtual table using a CTE (Common Table Expression).

If you manage to do that and store in in a structure like

```
-- ExclusionIntervals (start datetime, end datetime)
```

You could use

```
SELECT sv.Timestamp,
       sv.SignalID,
       s.SignalName,
       sv.Value
FROM SignalValue sv
       INNER JOIN Signal s ON s.SignalID = sv.SignalID
       INNER JOIN Device r ON r.DeviceID = s.DeviceID
       LEFT JOIN ExclusionIntervals ei ON ei.start <= sv.Timestamp AND ei.end >= sv.Timestamp 
WHERE  s.SignalName = Sensor1 AND r.DeviceId = 1 AND sv.timestamp >= '2019-02-04 00:00:00.000000' AND sv.timestamp <= '2019-02-11 23:59:59.999999'
AND ei.start is null
```

Comment: excelent, I implemented a CTE, was quite easy. The amount of characters is now okay, but now I'm limited by a max. amount of 2000 values in the `params`. I've to look for another solution for that. But my question was solved very well, thanks:)